# A user management system for a new app?

Tags: python, language-agnostic

im using python.  is there a widely accepted way of doing it?  it deals with some data management things, so i dont want to implement it like in stackoverflow, with anonymous accounts.  i also don't want to roll my own system from scratch.  any recommendations?

Comment: 1) What kind of app?  Please provide some hint as to what technology you're using.  2) The python tag should not be used with "language-agnostic".  The language is Python.  3) Please use Upper Case letters for proper nouns like "I".  Please update your question to tell what kind of application, remove the "language-agnostic" tag and fix your spelling.

Comment: well, i'm using python, but its more of a philosophy question

Comment: Please learn to use correct grammar. Professionals use professional language to communicate. Sentences begin with capital letters. This is not a hard thing to remember. It's one thing to make the occasional typo, but to refuse to use capitals is unprofessional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about a *web* application?  If so, [OpenId](http://openid.net/) is probably the way to go, and [this library](http://openidenabled.com/python-openid/) probably the most popular way to implement it in Python.  If you're talking about user management for a NON-web app, please clarify your requirements and constraints!

Comment: yes, definitely a web app.  thinking of doing facebook route too, but not sure how to intergrate everything

Comment: You can add Facebook Connect later -- first get OpenId to work, which gets you every decently-open authentication supplier;-).  Have you read the two URLs I linked to?  What problems are you seeing w/them?